# How can you dependency inject an service into an IHostedService (scheduled job)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, service

**The intend:** I want to build a cronjob, that overrides incache memory with the current data. It should be a separate service.

I have an IHostedService called TimedHostedService and a custom service called ExampleService. Example should be injected into TimedHostedService, so it can call a method from ExampleService.
ExampleService should be the only service to override the memory

**The Problem:** Program crashes when it tries to inject ExampleService into TimedHostedService. The following error message comes.

> AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: Example_Project.Backend.Job.TimedHostedService': Cannot consume scoped service 'Example_Project.Services.IExampleService' from singleton 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService'.)
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(IEnumerable serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)
>
> InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service
> descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService
> Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType:
> Example_Project.Backend.Job.TimedHostedService': Cannot consume
> scoped service 'Example_Project.Services.IExampleService' from
> singleton 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService'.

**The code**

StartUp.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        /* Add MemoryCache */
        services.AddMemoryCache();

        /* Add CronJob / Scheduled Job */
        services.AddHostedService<TimedHostedService>();

        /* Add Dependency Injection of ExampleService */
        services.AddScoped<IExampleService, ExampleService>();
}
```

ExampleService.cs

```
public interface IExampleService
{
    void SetExample();
    IInventoryArticle[] GetExamples();
}

public class ExampleService : IExampleService
{
    public Examples[] GetExamples()
    { return null; }

    public void SetExample()
    { }

}
```

TimedHostedService.cs

```
public class TimedHostedService : IHostedService, IDisposable
    {
        private readonly ILogger<TimedHostedService> _logger;
        private Timer _timer;
        private readonly IInventoryService _inventoryService;

        public TimedHostedService(
            ILogger<TimedHostedService> logger,
            IInventoryService inventoryService)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _inventoryService = inventoryService; /// Problem Child
        }
}
```

Comment: You could check the document([Consuming a scoped service in a background task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task)) to create a scoped service, Besides, You could refer to my reply in this thread and create a scheduled job use the [Cronos](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Cronos) package and the Cron Expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wish to use a scoped service you will need to create a scope yourself;

```cs
        private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

        public TimedHostedService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
            //...
        }

        public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
            {
                var ... = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<...>();
                //...
            }
        }
```